# Java XPath Prefix must resolve to a namespace

Tags: xpath

I'm having difficulty getting my XPath expression to work with Java. I am using XPath 1.0.

If I use https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html the following works:

```
/*:configuration/*:connectionStrings/*:add[@*:name= 'Data.Server.ConnectionString']/@name
```

When I try the same in my java program, it gives me:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace:
```

I  tried replacing the : with local-name() since I'm using XPath 1.0 but had no luck.

Here's the source document

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="telerik.web.ui">
  <section allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" name="radCompression" requirePermission="false" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompressionConfigurationSection, Telerik.Web.UI, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<telerik.web.ui>
  <radCompression enablePostbackCompression="true"/>
</telerik.web.ui>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="InfrastructureConfig.Server" value="[App.BaseDirectory]\infrastructure.config"/>
      <add key="InfrastructureConfig.Debug" value="[App.BaseDirectory]\Infrastructure.config"/>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
      <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled"/>
      <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled"/>
      <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="data source=[DB.Instance.Name];persist security info=True;user id=[DB.UserName];password=[DB.Password]" name="Data.Server.ConnectionString"/>
    <add connectionString="data source=[DB.Instance.Name];persist security info=True;user id=[DB.UserName];password=[DB.Password]" name="Data.Debug.ConnectionString"/>
</connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

I need to return connectionString and name.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `*:xxx` requires XPath 2.0+. Upgrade to an XPath 2.0 processor (there are several available in the Java world), or if you must, use the workaround `*[local-name()='xxx']`.

Comment: Like this?

/*[local-name()=configuration]/*[local-name()=connectionStrings]/*[local-name()=add][@name= 'Data.Server.ConnectionString']/@connectionString

Comment: No, you need quotes around the names.

Comment: /*[local-name()='configuration']/*[local-name()='connectionStrings']/*[local-name()='add'][@name= 'Data.Server.ConnectionString']/@connectionString

Doesn't work. I must be missing something

Comment: Can't help you without seeing the source document.

Comment: added source document

Comment: using XPath 1.0??

Comment: as soon as I put   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect newVersion="5.0.505.0" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.505.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime> into the source document, it doesn't work

Comment: I said it worked on the document you showed us. I didn't say it would work on some other random document.

Answer (score 0):

One shortest (but less secure) way to grab this could be :

```
//*[@connectionString and @name]/@*
```

If you face an error, use :

```
//*[@connectionstring and @name]/@*
```